# Unity game crashing on start on android device. What can be done to overcome the problem?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have built the game in unity and install it on android device. But it doesn't open at start. In the adb log events I can see that it crashed because of this error,
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class : "com.example.companyname.UnityPlayerActivity"

I also have edited manifest file. But nothing seems to be working.
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you entered your own Package Name?

Go to Edit -> Project Settings -> Player -> Android tab -> Edit "Bundle Identifier" to have form of `com.YourCompany.YourAppName`

If so, please post the logs from adb

Comment: Yes I have the correct package name for my game. Please check error logs in this image. https://imgur.com/UQi5YmL